# Gantry PHP Notice: Undefined property: Gantry::$belatedPNG

Tags: php, gantry

So I'm running the master Gantry template however I'm constantly hitting the following PHP notice in my error log - like 20/30 times a day:
`PHP Notice:  Undefined property: Gantry::$belatedPNG in /JROOT/libraries/gantry/features/belatedpng.php on line 44` (where obviously I've substituted JROOT in for my actual path). However I can't see it on all the pages on my site - so I'm wondering if it's bot's crawling onto a non-html page (I noticed before there was a gantry error when viewing feeds for example that I fixed).

Now Gantry don't offer free support as I'm aware (and it's just a personal site so I'm not gonna spend $'s on it) so I was wondering if anyone had come across this problem before or knew of any way to fix it.

Comment: What's the code on the line 44 ?

Comment: ```$fixes = $gantry->belatedPNG;``` gantry is a global ```global $gantry;``` that I haven't been able to nail down

Comment: It's bad. The problem is deeper then I thought. And globals are also bad... Seems like a modification should be made in the init point of `belatedPNG`.

Comment: That was my opinion as well! But I can't believe that someone else somewhere doesn't know how to fix it :P

Comment: Which versions of Joomla, Gantry Framework and Gantry template are you using? Which versions of Akeeba extensions are you using (if any)?

Comment: Latest Gantry (4.1.23), latest Joomla 3.x (3.2.3) and as I stated in the question the gantry default template. I have admin tools only from akeeba

Comment: Maybe try updating both Gantry Framework and Gantry template to v4.1.24 and update Akeeba Admin tools to the latest version (v2.6.2) too.

Comment: Akeeba Admin is latest. Dunno how i missed the gantry update staring me in the face but updated it and it hasn't appeared to have made any difference still same error same line. Out of interest why is akeeba extensions a problem? Akeeba strapper??

Comment: `NOTICE` in PHP can be safely ignored-- it's usually a minor code issue that will not affect anything. In production sites, log errors, turn off `display_errors`, and I usually ignore `NOTICES` in `error_reporting`

Comment: It's not something that I'm desperate to fix. It's just something I'd *like* to

Answer (score 3):

BelatedPNG is a method of fixing transparent PNG backgrounds for IE6.  Gantry and Rockettheme haven't supported IE6 in many months if not years.  This sounds like an older version of Gantry.

I'd update your Gantry version as well as your Gantry template files and Rockettheme extensions.  Something is a holdover here.

Comment: I only built this site ~6 months ago. I've updated to latest but it all still exists

Comment: The library itself on that line is :
  <code>if ($gantry->browser->name == 'ie' && $gantry->browser->shortversion == '6') {
   $fixes = $gantry->belatedPNG;</code>

So it is only triggered when the user agent is ie6 or below.  That's going to be a weak bot or a mistake.

Comment: Well that's how I saw it. But this is just a small personal site and I'm getting 20/30 of those php notices every day. And it's just something that would be nice to fix :p hence the question